# AngularJS mouse leave trigger misses

Tags: angularjs

On my web page, I have an array of

```
<div ng-repeat='img in imgList'>
    <div class='img_container' ng-mouseover="show(img)" ng-mouseleave="hide(img)">
        <div>one thumbnail</div>
        <div class='overlay_edit' ng-show='img.isShowEdit'></div>
    </div>
</div>

    // from controller
    $scope.hide = function hide(img){
        img.isShowEdit = false;
    }

    $scope.show = function show(img){
        if(img.metas != undefined && img.metas.length > 0){
            // a few lines of codes to use img.metas to 
            // format the edit div block, omitted for simplicity
            // but it does involve calling a REST service call
            // to retrieve all meta properties.
            img.isShowEdit = true;
        }
    }
```

The overlay edit div shows when mouse enters the container div and hides when mouse leaves the container div.

The problem I have is that I see lots of ghost overlays when mouse moves too quickly across many containers.

What would be the best way to tackle this problem?

Edited to add additional info and correct errors.

Comment: could you show the show() function ?

Comment: Added show() and also corrected errors.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the show() takes some time to complete.  If ng-mouseleave trigger takes place before show() completes, ng-mouseleave's trigger has no net effect.  When I moved the "img.isShowEdit = true;" to the beginning of show() body it solved the ghost issues.  Thanks to Narek for pointing out the show() function as the possible source of issue.